# Send Message Box or print PDF button

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am new to Odoo 8 and I work on a module, I create a view with a button to send an appeal and I want that when I click the button it prints me a PDF or use it opens a box sends message I want to know what is the easiest solution and if possible send me some examples that I can use the two solutions ..

Thank you again to you

Comment: Hi @Smith  welcome to stackoverflow , here we ask other for help not for the complete solution from scratch level , "what code you have done so far , post the code here first "

Comment: Hi @Prakash Sharma :  I do not ask for compléte solution but I am a beginner and I look for example to create a button to send a message

Comment: My advice to you is to calm down and take things one at a time. if you follow these links properly you should be able to achieve everything you want https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html and https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-send-a-message-programmatically-3389 ....Good luck